# Sencha Touch 2 association problems

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I get from server next JSON:

```
{
    "contextPath":"http://apps.dhis2.org/demo",
    "user":{
        "id":"GOLswS44mh8",
        "name":"System Administrator",
        "isAdmin":true,
        "ou":{
             "id":"ImspTQPwCqd",
             "name":"Sierra Leone"
        }
     }
}
```

I need convert this JSON in two Models : **User** model and **OrganizationUnit** model.

I read this tutorial http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader so it my code :

**User** model :

```
Ext.define('mobile-visualizer.model.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: [
            {name: 'id',  type: 'string'},
            {name: 'name',   type: 'string'},
            {name: 'isAdmin', type: 'boolean'}
        ],
        hasOne: {
            model: "mobile-visualizer.model.OrganizationUnit",
            name: "ou"
        },
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url : 'http://apps.dhis2.org/demo/dhis-web-visualizer/initialize.action',
            method : 'GET',
            withCredentials : true,
            useDefaultXhrHeader : false,
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'user'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**OrganizationUnit** model :

```
Ext.define('mobile-visualizer.model.OrganizationUnit', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: [
            {name: 'id',  type: 'string'},
            {name: 'name',   type: 'string'}
        ],
        belongsTo: 'mobile-visualizer.model.User'
    }
});
```

**Store** :

```
Ext.define('mobile-visualizer.store.UsersStore', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
    model : "mobile-visualizer.model.User",
    autoLoad : false,
    storeId : "usersStore",

    proxy : {
        type : 'ajax',
        url : 'http://apps.dhis2.org/demo/dhis-web-visualizer/initialize.action',
        method : 'GET',
        withCredentials : true,
        useDefaultXhrHeader : false,
        reader : {
            type : 'json',
            rootProperty : 'user'
        }
    }
});
```

So, when I try get user from store using another code :

```
        var store = Ext.create('mobile-visualizer.store.UsersStore');
        store.load({
                    callback : function() {
                        // the user that was loaded
                        var user = store.first();
                        console.log(user.ou())
                    }
                });
```

I have error : ***Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'ou'***

I **can get all information about user** but I can't get **ou** from **user**. It look like some association issue.

But I make all as like official tutorial . Please help to resolve this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: `console.log(user.get('ou'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow my rules and everything will come out rosy:

http://extjs-tutorials.blogspot.ca/2012/05/extjs-hasmany-relationships-rules.html

http://extjs-tutorials.blogspot.ca/2012/05/extjs-belongsto-association-rules.html

These are for extjs, but very similar for sencha touch.

You are forgetting the **associationKey**.

Also, no need to redefine proxy in store as it will inherit its model's proxy.

Also, a user probably belongs to an org unit and doesn't have one...